# Has Macron explained which outcomes/situations he thinks (or perhaps was even let on by Putin) would be "humiliating" for Russia?

Tags: russian-federation, ukraine, france, foreign-policy

A fair bit of commentary [has](https://thehill.com/opinion/international/3513708-russias-humiliation-is-unavoidable/) been written about Macron saying that Russia must not be "humiliated" in this war. Zelensky, for instance, [said](https://www.ft.com/content/37d511b4-a127-4a17-bd6c-260e3744a0d5) he doesn't understand what Macron is talking about. So, has Macron clarified how he sees peace happen (other than the fact it should be at the negotiation table)? Has Macron suggested any concrete steps that Ukraine must avoid, like not hold any war crimes trials? (The Russia delegation at the peace talks [was](https://www.reuters.com/world/lavrov-says-west-trying-derail-russia-ukraine-talks-with-hysteria-over-bucha-2022-04-05/) clearly upset by some of this war-crimes talk). Or is there something else [concrete] maybe that Macron sees Ukraine must or mustn't do?

(For me Macron's comments are miffing because France has stepped up overt military aid for Ukraine, [including](https://www.rferl.org/a/ukraine-artillery-french-caesar-howitzer-donbas-russia/31892607.html) self-propelled howitzers, in recent weeks.)

Comment: What I'm missing from those critical of Macron in this regard is a remotely credible different outcome. Ukrainian tanks rolling into Moscow won't happen. Perhaps a solution where Ukraine accepts the loss of Crimea in exchange for retreats and reparations elsewhere? But that won't happen if leaders stake uncompromising public stances.

Comment: I see now that Macron might have possibly been taking a swipe at some (earlier) UK statements that Putin was "humiliating himself" in Ukraine... and that Russia should be "pushed out of "the whole of Ukraine"." https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-61432502 The Russians in particular appear to have been riled by this with Lavrov saying "I don't think there's even room for manoeuvre any more, because both [Prime Minister Boris] Johnson and [Liz] Truss say openly that we should defeat Russia, we should force Russia to its knees. Go on, then, do it!" Possibly they told Macro that too.

Answer (score 2):

No, he has not.

The proof is by *argumentum ex silencio* - if he did say something it would've been [reported](https://www.euronews.com/2022/06/06/ukraine-war-what-has-macron-said-about-the-need-not-to-humiliate-russia), but it hasn't been.

> **What did Macron actually say?**
>
> ...
>
> "The situation is worrying, it's true. That's why I've put so much time and energy into it. I have lost count of the conversations I have had with Vladimir Putin since December. In all, about a hundred hours in transparency and at the request of Volodymyr Zelenskyy. We must not humiliate Russia so that the day the fighting stops, we can build a way out through diplomatic channels. I am convinced that it is France's role to be a mediating power," Macron replied.

Comment: Please add relevant sections from the linked page. Otherwise this becomes a link only answer. You say he didn't but in the answer it doesn't become clear what people have searched for. What did Euronews find out?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. However is that all he said on that? Maybe he said something else at some other point. How have you searched for this? Sorry to comment so much but I think that the right way to show something didn't take place would be to describe the research.

Answer (score -3):

From the [EuroNews source](https://www.euronews.com/2022/06/06/ukraine-war-what-has-macron-said-about-the-need-not-to-humiliate-russia) it is seen that the French president also said that it is important to "**never give in to the temptation either of humiliation or of a spirit of revenge**". He referred to that happened for Germany in 1919, with heavy territorial losses and reparations, which led to a new world war. For instance, Kaliningrad region has been lost that remains Russia up to now.

Logically thinking, this means that after winning the war Ukraine should not take additional territories of Russia like [Taganrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taganrog) or [Belgorod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belgorod) for instance, or maybe return them back after peace agreement if would have been taken due the logical development of the war. Also, the burden of reparations must be such as not to destroy the Russian economy completely, not the [second Haiti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haiti_indemnity_controversy). Political decisions should not be dictated just by revenge.

Russian PR now [paints the possible defeat](https://cepa.org/article/whisper-it-russia-begins-to-discuss-defeat/) as a total disaster: "we will see the bloody disintegration of a country". France then will say this is not that is desired for the safety of Europe. Makes sense.